# SQL Finding Values from tables where one column has the same value multiple times

Tags: sql

[Table Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4RZo.png)

If I have a column with multiple values I want to find a way to return rows where there specific columns with the same value. For example:

```
| Name | School    | Year | Gender |
---------------------------------
| John | St Mark's |  1   |    M   |
| Paul | St Mark's |  1   |    M   |
| David| St Peter's|  2   |    M   |
| Sally| St Mark's |  3   |    F   |
| Lucy | St Peter's|  1   |    M   |
```

If I want to return all rows where students are in the same year and the same school, without having to specify which school or year. I want to query to be able to identify any instance where there are more than one student with the same School and Year value.

I then want to be able to split those results by gender.

Thanks.

Comment: A [mcve] is expected to include both sample table data _and_ the expected result.

Comment: where is your attempt?

Comment: Also add a tag for the dbms you're using.